# PHP How to GROUP BY result array when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Please to simplify the explanation of my problem, let's say that I've done a small sql query to select data from three tables :

```
SELECT  blockTitre, ChampsType, ChampsNom
FROM form_builder
    LEFT JOIN block_champs
        ON formBuilderBId = blockId
    RIGHT JOIN ajout_champs
        ON ChampsId = formBuilderChId
```

and When I var_dump the result I get the following :

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[8]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Misc' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'submit' (length=6)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'submit' (length=6)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Misc' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'hidden' (length=6)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'page' (length=4)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Information général' (length=21)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'email' (length=5)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Information général' (length=21)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'prenom' (length=6)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Information général' (length=21)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'age' (length=3)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'blockTitre' => string 'Misc' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsType' => string 'text' (length=4)
      public 'ChampsNom' => string 'nommm' (length=5)
```

What I want is to regroup result by **blockTitre**.

I tried the SQL statement `GROUP BY` but it returns only two lines (It's logic I think) !

Please masters how to do to get all lines grouped by **blockTitre**  ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**

Please I need to get something like :

```
 0 =>
       'blockTitre' => string 'Misc' 
            'ChampsType' => string 'submit' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'submit'
            'ChampsType' => string 'text' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'nommm' 
            'ChampsType' => string 'hidden' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'page' 
  1 =>     
       'blockTitre' => string 'Information général' 
            'ChampsType' => string 'text' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'email' 
            'ChampsType' => string 'text' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'prenom' 
            'ChampsType' => string 'text' 
            'ChampsNom' => string 'age'
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` works as you describe your situation. It will leave only unique values: `Misc` and `Information général`. It will take the first row it sees for the values of the other columns. So indeed, you will get only 2 rows.

What is the output that you're looking for? Typically you use `GROUP BY` to either get only unique values, or to do some sort of `COUNT`ing.

Keep in mind that SQL can only give you 'flat' data, that is, a structure like:

```
data = {
    "misc": [{
        "row1",
        "row2"
    }],
    "info": [{
        "row1",
        "row2"
    }]
 }
```

is something that would have to do yourself by reading the result set line by line.

Comment: Yes But I don't want to get only the first row it sees, I need theme all. Is it possible please ?

Comment: If you want all rows, don't use `GROUP BY`. Why are you using `GROUP BY`? What do you want your result set to look like?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what MySQL can't do for you. Leave out the `GROUP BY` and do the grouping logic yourself in PHP.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for explaining me this. Have please any way in php to doing it ? I can't image How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` if you're using PDO.

To fetch your results grouped by `blockTitre`, try this (assuming you've already executed the query with PDO):

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

More information can be found [in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-parameters).

Now, you can loop through the groups however you like. Just make sure to

```
GROUP BY blockTitre
```

in your query.

Comment: I'm using MySQLi. What's the equivalent please ?

Comment: Just had a quick look through the docs, and it doesn't appear there is an equivalent in MySQLi. You could loop through the result set from `$res->fetchAll()` and group it yourself.